# Error passing object to method using send() in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I'm having a problem using `send()` to call a method while passing said method an object. I receive an ``` undefined method ``employee_feedback(#<WorkItem:0x000000057cc7c0>)' for WorkItemMailer:Class ``` error.

This is in my work_item.rb model:

```
  def send_work_item_mail
    forms_needing_mail = ["employee", "install", "repair"]
    if forms_needing_mail.include?(self.form)
      WorkItemMailer.send("#{self.form}_feedback(#{self})").deliver_now
    end
  end
```

Which is being called as:

```
  @work_item.send_work_item_mail
```

in my work_items_controller.rb

And the following is the method in my mailer:

```
  def employee_feedback(work_item)
    @work_item = work_item
    @employee  = User.find_by(id: @work_item.employee)
    @manager   = User.find_by(id: @employee.manager)
    mail to: @manager.email, subject: "Employee feedback for #{@employee.name}"
  end
```

Am I using send incorrectly, or is there something else at play here?

Comment: the `` are typo or they are present in the exception?, if it is not a typo this is the problem.

Comment: Typo. Added it in for when pasting it into my explanation as the ` was stopping the code formatting from working properly.

Comment: The metaprogramming tag should be removed. `send` is about as basic as you can get.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: well, not that super basic. But yes, far from "meta".

Comment: @Sergio, I've always regarded `puts "It's a fine day"` as syntactic sugar for `send(:puts, "It's a fine day.")` (for public methods).

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I guess, it depends on which manuals you start learning ruby from. :)

Comment: Having parentheses in the name of a method is very unusual. Are you sure that's the correct method name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `send` on an object is identical as calling a method directly. The difference is that you pass the method name as an argument to `send`.
Subsequent arguments to send, (after the method name) are passed as parameters in the method

So this:

```
WorkItemMailer.employee_feedback(self)
```

Should be called as:

```
WorkItemMailer.send(:employee_feedback, self)
```

In your case:

```
WorkItemMailer.send("#{self.form}_feedback", self).deliver_now
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. Works great. Didn't need to pass it as an array though - just `self` worked fine.

Comment: What's up with the array?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
WorkItemMailer.send("#{self.form}_feedback".to_sym, self).deliver_now
```

Comment: Thanks. Still receiving the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: if you run WorkItemMailer.send("employee_feedback(#{WorkItem.first})").deliver_now from the console you get an error?

Comment: Sure do - `NoMethodError: undefined method ``employee_feedback(WorkItem.first)' for WorkItemMailer:Class`

Comment: Looks like the problem is with `send()` looking for the entire string as a method, rather than passing the object as the argument - it's passing the object ID as a string as part of the method call.

Comment: Whoops, I made a typo (forgot the #{}), but I'm getting the same error as before from the console

Comment: No need for `.to_sym`